# VB.NET MS ACCESS

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I just started using MS Access as my database and my problem now is how to display my lastname and firstname combined as "`Name`". Here's my MySQL code:

```
CONCAT(Surname, ', ', Firstname) as Name
```

How to convert this in access database SQL?
How can I make it appear as `Name` using access database because it seems `CONCAT()` is not supported in MS Access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no CONCAT() function in MS Access. You should just use the string concatenation operator which is ampersand:

```
SELECT (Surname & ' ' & Firstname) AS FullName
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the '&' character to concatenate things.

https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/string/concat.php

Answer (score 0):

you could use a calculated column in a query or a formula within a form - depending how many times you want to type it. If you put it in a query, you can use the ampersand (&) to join values as there is no CONCAT function.

I don't know the name of your table, but you could easily adapt the script below to work for you.

```
SELECT Table1.*, [Table1].[LastName] & ", " & [Table1].[FirstName] AS FullNameLastFirst FROM Table1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

If you want to display in a text box

```
TextBox1.Text =  txtFn.text + " "  + txtLn.text
```

it will show as follows

> First[space]Last

Ex- smith ryan

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this as a new field in a query you can also do this:

```
Name: [Surname] & "," & [Firstname]
```

Note: I do not recommend using 'Name' as a field name in MS Access as it might be confused with a reserved keyword.